# Some plugs are failing to open in Switchboard

Tags: settings, keyboard

[image: This is my picture]
As you can see i have two diffrent gnome control centers.
The left is default , open from application.
The right was opened by Ternimal `gnome-control-center`.
The left can't open Keyboard
The right doesn't have it ,but can open keyboard by `gksu gnome-control-center`

My linux distro is elementary os Freya

Comment: `gnome-control-center keyboard` Is it opening keyboard settings?

Comment: Hello Ravan. you again. `Could not find settings panel "keyboard"`

Comment: try this: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center` and lt me know =)

Comment: That was first thing i done for 2 diffrent gnome-control-centers.
It didnt remove the old ( default) , it installed new one ( terminal )

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center`

Comment: The left still appear and working on `Application` but Terminal didn't

Comment: try this: `sudo apt-get purge gnome-control-center*`

Comment: Still appear but lost some options

Answer (score 3):

The one on the left is Switchboard, not GNOME Control Center. It looks like you've made several modifications to your system. One of these modifications likely resulted in installing GNOME Control Center and breaking your installation.

The easiest solution would be to just do a clean install and don't make those modifications on the new system.

Alternatively, you could try reverting your modifications, removing GNOME Control Center and re-installing the `switchboard-plug-gcc-*` packages that are failing to open in Switchboard

Comment: Can't remove the left with `sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center`

Comment: @QuangVu no you can't. Because it's not GNOME Control Center. it's Switchboard.

Comment: OK but the keyboard didn't work

Comment: In my case, that uninstalled some somponents, the switchboard-plug-gcc-* did the job to recover them, but some icons now are repeted.